# Codeigniter - Chrome autofill change input value after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, google-chrome

Is quite simple but very strange.
I'm using Codeigniter, i've an App where an User can create other users and then change their passwords.

For this reason i've a simple form as the following:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("Manage/changeUserPassword"); ?>" method="post">
    <input hidden class="inputwithiduser" type="text" name="iduser" value="">
    <input type="password" id="inputPasswd" name="password" placeholder="New password" value="">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I fill the first input (with class inputwithiduser) with JQuery. 
Inspectioning, these inputs have the correct values. BUT.... AFTER SUBMIT my controller retrieve as **$this->input->post("iduser");** the value that Chrome has saved as Username for my personal login. In other words, CHROME is changing my input (despite inspecting the iduser input with Chrome tool it's all okay) after submit!

Have you any ideas? I tried with `autocomplete="off"`, `autocomplete="false"`, etc without success.

Thank, Luca

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `autocomplete="foo"` (or whatever value)? New browsers use this attribute different as they used it before

Comment: but.. can Chrome's autofill change my input value?! Also if i read something else inspectioning

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and finally i solved by this:

```
  <input type="text" name="username" hidden/>
  <input type="password" name="password" hidden/>
```

add two input before your oiriginal input.